# How to get black shadow around the image dynamicaly?

Tags: android, image-processing

I am working on image processing i have achieved color effect using ColorMatrix but i cant understand how to achieved one effect that is not on whole image but only around the image like i have attached image. Actually i m working on image editor app like : [BeFunkey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.befunky.BeFunkyPhotoEditor&hl=en)

[image: Original Image]

[image]

Here original image and processed image i have attached. You can see in effect on second image that is only around the image black shadow. Please can anybody tell me how to do this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: tahts image designer work.. i guess cannot be done programtically

Comment: grammatically?   Or programtically?

Comment: I want to do some thing like Befunky : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.befunky.BeFunkyPhotoEditor&hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set RGB colors of you bitmaps. Have a look over [android-image-filter](https://github.com/ragnraok/android-image-filter)

This demo will fulfill your requirements.